# Plotting sinusoids from a WAV file

Tags: python, spyder

```
import numpy as np
import wave
import struct
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
file = "One_Life.wav"
amplitude = 30000
frequency = 100
duration = 3
fs = 44100
num_samples = duration * fs

num_channels = 1
sampwidth = 2
num_frames = num_samples
comptype = "NONE"
compname = "not compressed"

t = np.linspace(0, duration, num_samples, endpoint = False)
x = amplitude * np.cos(2*np.pi * frequency * t )


wav_file = wave.open(file,'w')
wav_file.setparams((num_channels, sampwidth,fs,num_frames,comptype,compname))

for s in x: 
  wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h',int(s)))

wav_file.close()


plt.plot(t,x) 
plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]

However, it must be like this:

[image]

Comment: maybe you have too many samples so there is no place to show space between waves.

Comment: @furas Actually I thought about this too

Comment: @furas so you mean, it is correct code ?

Comment: if I use `fs = 30` instead of `fs = 44100` then I see some waves. Code can be OK but there is too many waves to show them as you expect.

Comment: @furas you're right, thank you !